# Updating view with setViewCube in v7

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How do i update the view using setViewCube in v7? I was using the following code in v6, but it doesn't work in v7.

```
viewer.setViewCube('[top/front]');
```

In the migration guide v6 to v7 it says, I should call it through the extension:

```
extension.setViewCube(display);
```

How do I get the extension object from where to call it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [migration document mentions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/): The ViewCube apis have been moved out of Viewer3D instance and into the Autodesk.ViewCubeUi extension. So you will need to get the extension by

```
viewcuiext = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.ViewCubeUi')
viewcuiext.setViewCube(display);
```

this assumes the extension has been loaded, otherwise, call

```
   viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.ViewCubeUi')
          .then(res=>console.log('the extension has been loaded: ' + res))
```

loadExtension is a promise call, so ensure it has been loaded successfully.

Please let us know if there is any question.

Comment: Thanks @Xiaodong, just for those who see this solution, what the Promise return is a reference to the extension, so you can simply do : viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.ViewCubeUi')
          .then(ext=>ext.setViewCube('back'))