# Set View Cube function in APS Viewer Version 7*

Tags: javascript, autodesk-viewer

In the API documentation for all of the APS viewer versions (except version 7) have the function **viewer.setViewCube(face)**. In version 7 has this been replaced with a different function?

I would like to make use of the function to rotate the viewer without having to use THREE.js camera transformations.

I attempted to use the function viewer.setViewCube(face) on the GuiViewer3D class. But the console said that it wasn't a valid function. I looked at the docs for the GuiViewer3D class for version 7 and found that the function wasn't there.

Comment: Please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321876/updating-view-with-setviewcube-in-v7/57322133#57322133

Comment: Awesome thank you! Not sure how I missed that post